# react native app needs to be deployed on multiple store listings at once [both android and ios]

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-play, app-store

We have a SaaS platform where tenets can opt for a dedicated (white labeled) mobile apps for both platforms - Android + iOS. Programmatically its the same app cooked for multiple tenets on both ios and android platforms under different names. We want a CI/CD for both stores, meaning once we push an update to master branch of our react native app - a system should make a build and deploy to both store apps and update all android apps and ios apps automatically, how is this possible? what tools will i need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppCenter and Fastlane helps you to accomplish that.

AppCenter connects your repo to it's own server to automatically build and push to Google Play and App Store.

https://appcenter.ms

Fastlane used to create metadatas, versioning for apps, distribute new releases to both stores:

https://fastlane.tools